# Using require.js for client side dependancies in Adobe CQ5

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, aem, chaplinjs

I was wondering if anyone had experience using require.js with the Adobe CQ5 platform.  I'm writing a Chaplin.js(backbone-based) single page app that will be integrated into the rest of CQ5-based site we're working on.  Chaplin requires the use of a module system like AMD/Common.js and I want to make sure my compiled javascript file will usable within CQ5's clientlibs.  Is it as simple as adding require.js as a dependency in clientlibs prior to loading in my javascript modules?  Someone's insight who has experience in doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd consider that require and clientlibs are two tools for the same problem — require.js plays nicely if you manually add it to your template.

You could always forego clientlibs & just use require as per any other site?

Comment: I'm with @anotherdave. ClientLibs have been buggy in the past, especially with regards to minifying. My suggestion is use Client Tech like RequireJS to handle Client concerns.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented this as a solution of organize in a better way all the modules such as:

```
//public/js/modules/myModule.js
define('myModule',[ /* dependencies */] ,function( /* stuff here */ ))
```

and in the components such:

```
<% //components/component.jsp %>
<div>
  <!-- stuff here -->
</div>
```

componentJS:

```
//components/component/clientlibs/js/component.js
require(['modules/myModule']);
```

and finally I've configured require (`config.js`) and I've stored the JSs modules in a new different  design folder. Located the compiled JS after close `</body>` to guarantee the JS is always located at the bottom after the HTML.

```
<!-- page/body.jsp -->
...
  <cq:includeClientLib js="specialclientlibs.footer"/>
</body>
```

solving with this the issue of have "ready" all the content before the JS is executed. I've had some problems to resolve with this async stuff managed for the clienlibs compilation tool, in production the problem was different, however, in development, the order in what CQ compiles the JS has produced me some lacks in terms of order of the JS. The problem really was a little bit more complex than the explanation because the number of JS was really big and the team too, but in simple terms it was the best way I've discovered so far..

Answer (score 1):

**The Idea**

I think you can compile your Chaplin.js with one of the AMDShims to make it self contained, wraps every dependencies it needs inside a function scope, expose an entry point as global variable (which is a bad practise, but CQ do it all the time...) and then use the compiled.js inside a normal clientlib:

**AMD Shims**

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/AMD-API-Shims

**Example**

Here is an example of how we make the one of our libs self-contained:

https://github.com/normanzb/chuanr/blob/master/gruntfile.js

Basically, in source code level the lib "require"s the other modules just as usual. However after compiled, the generated chuanr.js file contains everything its needs, even wrapped a piece of lightweight AMD compatible implementation.

check out compiled file here: https://github.com/normanzb/chuanr/blob/master/Chuanr.js

and the source code: https://github.com/normanzb/chuanr/tree/master/src

**Alternative**

Alternatively rather than compile every lib you are using to be independent/self-contained, what we do in our project is simply use below amdshim instead of the real require.js. so on cq component level you can call into require() function as usual:

```
require(['foo/bar'], function(){});
```

The amd shim will not send the http request to the module immediately, instead it will wait until someone else loads the module.

and then at the bottom of the page, we collect all the dependencies, send the requirements to server side handler (scriptmananger) for dynamic merging (by internally calling into r.js):

```
var paths = [];
for (var path in amdShim.waiting){
     paths.push(path);
}
document.write('/scriptmananger?' + paths.join(','));
```

The amdShim we are using: https://github.com/normanzb/amdshim/tree/exp/defer